Troubleshooting AUTH_USER_MODEL Migration Error in Django App
I am working on a Django application where I've set up **AUTH_USER_MODEL **with the name **User **for authentication purposes. However, when I tried to run migrations, I encountered the following error: django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1005, 'Can't create table myAppDjango.django_admin_log (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")'). Could someone assist me in properly generating my model and Django migrations to resolve this issue?
i used this commande to migrate model:
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
